# Operating System_Thread-Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, operating-system

Consider the image of the execution of 3 threads on the uniprocessor below. If all three threads on the image are executed with multiprocessor, redraw the execution order of the three threads! [Multithreading in Uniprocessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVsWU.png)

does anyone can redraw the execution order of the three threads ?

Answer (score 0):

> does anyone can redraw the execution order of the three threads ?

To do this with any accuracy you have to know:

- What caused Thread C to be created. Specifically, did Thread A create Thread C (e.g. by using a "fork()" or "system()" function to start Process 2) during its second time slice, and would Thread A running sooner cause Thread C to be created sooner.
- If there are 2 processors or "3 or more" processors, and/or what happens after. Specifically, if there's 2 processors you need to know if Thread B blocks or terminates before Thread C is started; and if there are 3 or more processors then you don't need to know what happens to thread B after (you can just fill in the gap on the right with an "unknown" section).